# cannot see values from list in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:
But i cannot response write the values in the list for debugging purposes...

```
 public void LottoWinners(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Dictionary<int, int> number = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        Random generator = new Random();
        while (number.Count < 6)
        {
            number[generator.Next(1, 49)] = 1;
        }

        int[] lotto = number.Keys.OrderBy(n => n).ToArray();

       List<int> lst = lotto.OfType<int>().ToList();


       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
       {
           builder.Append(lst).Append("|"); // Append string to StringBuilder
       }
       string result = builder.ToString(); // Get string from StringBuilder

       Response.Write(result);

    }
```

But all i see is as my result. I should be seeing the values of my list!

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what happens when you are calling `ToString` on `List<T>`. In your code this is happening right here:

```
builder.Append(lst)
```

All you have to do is to replace it with:

```
builder.Append(lst[i])
```

BTW you can replace this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
{
    builder.Append(lst).Append("|"); // Append string to StringBuilder
}
string result = builder.ToString(); // Get string from StringBuilder
```

with this:

```
string result = string.Join("|", lst) + "|";
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to do this:

```
builder.Append(lst[i])
```

to get the list element you're trying to access.  Currently you're just Appending the whole list, which isn't meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are appending the list object:

```
builder.Append(lst)
```

Instead of one item:

```
builder.Append(lst[i])
```

Other than this, your code seems fine

Answer (score 1):

`builder.append(lst)` is appending the list, which internally calls `ToString()`.  `ToString()`on a list returns

> > System.Collections.Generic.List`1

so this is the correct behavior.  What you want to do is this instead, use the indexer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
       {
           builder.Append(lst[i]).Append("|"); // Append string to StringBuilder
       }
```